# Check if point lies within 2D Implicit Function

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry, implicit-function

For a part of a project I am working on, I want to fill a shape defined by a 2D implicit function with evenly spaced points.

To do this, I've realised that I will need some way of knowing if the point in question lies within the area specified by the function.

The function is:

$$3\sin(2x)\cos(\frac{1}{2}y^2) = -x^2 - y^2+15$$

This looks like the following: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eh2pcgxq4x

Any help or assistance would be much appreciated :)

Comment: It is easy to modify to a form $f(x,y)=0$. For certain classes of functions  $f(x,y)$  location is determined by the sign of its value.

Comment: Hint: What happens if you use $\le$ instead of $=$ in your equation?  If you were to write your equation in the fully implicit form, but with that change, you'd get $$3 \sin\left(2 x\right) \cos\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right) + x^2 + y^2 - 15 \le 0$$Right? If you now change that $\le$ to $\gt$ you see the points that do *not* fulfill the equation.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it :). Does this hold true for three dimensional implicit functions as well ?

Comment: Yes, but but conditions required (e.g. continuity of $f$, set satisfying $f(x,y,z)=0$ properties ) become more complicated. Observe a simple example $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$